# How to pass string from a View to a controller in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This JavaScript code is being used to pass a string from a view to an action in a controller:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/brandsOfACategory',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset:utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(this.id)
        })
    });
</script>
```

brandsOfACategory code in the controller:

```
public ActionResult brandsOfACategory(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Code is not working as expected as id is coming as null.

Can someone please guide?

Comment: `this.id` may contain null - also no need to use `contentType` because you can pass it like `data: { id: "someid" }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/brandsOfACategory',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset:utf-8',
  data: { 'id': id }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ajax Code**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "controllerurl",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        id: "123"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        //Write your code here
    }
});
```

For more info about ajax [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**Parameter binding in ASP.Net** [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score -1):

With your current code, when the ajax call is made, the request payload has only a string value. For example, if your clicked link has an `Id` attribute value "link1", it will send the below string as the request payload for your ajax call.(You can see this if you open up your dev tools->network tab)

```
"link1"
```

For model binding to work, the payload should have a key-value format so that the value will be mapped to the parameter with the same value as the key.

Since it is a simple value, you do not need to necessarily send the JSON stringified version and the `contentType` as `application/json`. Simply send the JS object as `data`. Make sure you are sending a JavaScript object which has the key/property name same as your action method parameter name(`id`) and it will work.

Assuming your anchor tag has a valid `Id` attribute value so that the `this.id` expression returns the valid string value.

```
<a href="/SomeUrl" id="myId">MyLink</a>
```

In the script, you probably want to stop the normal click behavior as well to prevent the page from navigating to the href attribute value.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/brandsOfACategory',
        data: { id :this.id } 
    }).done(function (res) {
        console.log('result from ajax call',res);
    })
});
```

This will send the value like `id=myId` as the Form Data for the request. Since you are not specifying the contentType explicitly, it will use the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

If the link user clicked does not have an `Id` attribute, the code will send no value because `this.id` will return an empty string and your parameter value at server side will be null.